# Website Performance testing automated tools/frameworks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, testing, automated-tests

I have a website that uses AJAX heavily to communicate with the server. Now I want to do performance and stress testing using automatic scripts. Do you have any recommendations?

The functionality maybe, given a URL, hook up the page ready callback. In the callback I can emulate "click" to some button using the button's id property.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of tools you can use to automate the UX of your site to make sure that things work fine. I'll break them down arbitrarily.

The ones that come to mind are [Sahi](http://sahi.co.in/) and [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). These allow you to automate clicking, submitting etc. similar to what GUI testing tools do and test your application.

Mechanize ([Perl version](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.66/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)(the original), [Ruby version](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) and [python version](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)) are used to write scripts that can interact with your website to simulate a user. They're not "GUI" based so don't rely on a browser. This might affect what you can do with Javascript. Another similar tool (although I don't have personal experience with it) is [watir](http://watir.com/).

If you want to hammer your website (i.e. performance testing), they only thing I've come across is the [Apache Benchmarker](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html). It can generate reports on how much raw traffic your site can take before it comes crashing down. Assuming your callbacks are not stateful, you can use this to hammer them.

Answer (score 2):

use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of how effective Selenium is for performance testing, but it sure is good for testing in general... are there plugins/other tools that work well with it specifically for the performance aspect?

Comment: True. Selenium is more for functional rather than performance testing.

Comment: As far I know, it is good. also you can use selenium api to make your own automated tool to test. In case of that would be good in performance I am sure...

Comment: It would *perform* well. It wouldn't stress the site sufficiently to call it a performance test. `ab` can send in, for example send 10000 requests 100 at a time for 10 seconds to see if your site can take that load. Selenium is not designed to do that kind of thing.